# 2010 (?) science fiction TV show with new world

Tags: story-identification, tv

- **Plotline:** The government is sending a whole bunch of people to another planet to "prepare for Armageddon." I recall the trip taking a very long time (on the order of maybe 30 years). Also, one of the people dies and their death is investigated throughout the show.
- **Start Date:** Approximately 2010, I'd say.
- **Platform:** No idea.
- **Language:** English

---

Unfortunately, this is the extent of all the details I can recall. I'll make edits if I remember any more!

Comment: [Ascension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascension_(miniseries)) had a murder investigation as a major plot driver, and was based on a long-term colonization mission.  (I don't recall a specific reference to Armageddon, though.)

Comment: @DavidW - SFGITW! (Second FGITW) -- I'll explore and see if that's correct. Maybe post an answer?

Comment: @DavidW yeah, this is probably the answer... post it as such

Comment: This also sounds like it might be Terra Nova, a TV show where overpopulation on Earth was getting to be a problem so there was an idea of using a sort of Stargate-looking machine that would open a portal to a parallel Earth/planet that was still stuck in a semi-Cretaceous Period. Stargate with dinosaurs, in a way. But the "thirty year journey" part doesn't match up.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This sounds a lot like [*Ascension*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascension_(miniseries)), a [6-part TV miniseries](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt3696720/) from 2014.

*Ascension* is the name of a generation starship launched in the early 1960s to the Proxima Centauri system.  The trip will take 100 years, and the story opens at the midpoint of the trip (50 years) at which point the ship will start braking into the Proxima system.  (Though I think they got the physics of that wrong in the show.)

The plot is kicked off by the murder of a woman in the "lake" area, and the first episode in particular is focused on investigating the murder, though that thread continues through the series.

The Wikipedia article (linked above) notes that the impetus for launching the mission was the fear of a global nuclear war, so that could be the reference to Armageddon you recall.

Comment: +1 -- This seems correct, and I've explored a bit. I'll do a little more and will accept in a bit! :)

Comment: Is this the Ascension where the whole voyage turns out to be fake?

Comment: @PEW Yes, but that's kind of a massive spoiler...